# discord.js Private Voice Channel issue

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
  if (newState.channelId !== oldState.channelId) {
          const guildId = oldState.guild?.id || newState.guild?.id;
          const profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ GuildId: guildId })
          const event_channel = profileData?.auto_Voice
          if (event_channel && event_channel.enabled && newState.channelId === event_channel?.voice.id) {
              try {
                  const voice_channel = await newState.guild.channels.create({
                      name: `└ ${newState.member.user.username}`,
                      type: ChannelType.GuildVoice,
                      parent: newState.channel.parent,
                  })
                  _vc.push(voice_channel.id);
                  await wait(1000)
  
                  const member = newState.guild.members.cache.get(newState.member.id);
                  if (!member.voice.channelId) {
                      voice_channel.delete();
                  } else {
                      owner.push(newState.member.id)
                      await member.voice.setChannel(voice_channel);
                  }
```

Why when I'm inside `event_channel?.voice.id`,
I quickly adjust the mute button (which causes voiceStateUpdate to fire),
The next `if (newState.channelId !== oldState.channelId)` will be false
But my client shows that I am still in `event_channel?.voice.id`
Is it an api delay?

Comment: Did you include the GuildVoiceStates Intent?